# Page refreshes after javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

After I excecute my JS function over onClick button method. My site refreshes and everything that was writen with innerHTML is erased. I think i'm missing something. I will just put the whole JS function here. I probably don't understand something and that's what is causing it.

```
function stisk() {
  var stevilo = prompt("Vnesi iskano stevilo");
  var seznam = document.getElementById("vnos").value;
  var pattern = new RegExp("^[0-9](,\s*[0-9])+$");
  var vsota = 0;
  var seznam = seznam.split(',');

  var dolzina = seznam.length;
  var pravilnost = pattern.test(seznam);
  if (pravilnost == true) {
    for (i = 0; i < dolzina; i++) {
      vsota = vsota + parseInt(seznam[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dolzina - 1; i++) {
      var star = document.getElementById("stevila").innerHTML;
      if (isNaN(seznam[i]) == false) {
        var starejsi = document.getElementById("stevila").innerHTML = star + parseInt(seznam[i]) + "+";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("stevila").innerHTML = "Vnos ni pravilen";
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("stevila").innerHTML = starejsi + seznam[dolzina - 1] + "=" + vsota;
    var c = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < seznam.length; i++) {
      if (stevilo == seznam[i]) {
        c++;
      }
    }
    if (c == 0) {
      alert("stevila ni na seznamu");
    } else {
      alert("Stevilo je na seznamu");
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("stevila").innerHTML = "Napacen vnos stevil";
  }
}
```

**HTML:**
[image: HTML]
**Here is the browser view:**

[image: example]

**After i press "V redu" (OK) Everything goes back to the start, expacting me to write a number inside. I want the 2+3+4=9 to stay there if that is possible? Thanks**

Comment: Clicking on the `button` in the `form` submits the form by default. Add `type="button"` attribute to the tag to prevent submission.

Comment: @Teemu If i click "OK" when there are numbers inside the form, nothing happens. If the form is empty the function goes trough.

Comment: After you've added the type attribute? If so, then this is a whole new question. Please consider also to translate the variable names into English, it's really hard to read a code when you've no clue what the variables actually are purposed to hold.

Comment: @Teemu Yes after, it only submits 1 number. If i add commas like in the picture, nothing happens. But if i debugg it everything works fine, I'm confused. Never mind, i am dumb. If i press Enter it doesn't work, i have to actually click on the button.

Comment: @Teemu it isn't an array when it's tested, it becomes when i split it. I think.

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
<button onclick="stisk()">OK</button>
```

to:

```
<input type="button" onclick="stisk()">OK</input>
```

Like @Teemu said, < button > will submit a form element.

Comment: This works, thanks to Teemu and you. But if i press "Enter" nothing happens, i have to lituraly click on the button, it's weird. Is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: try: <input type="button" tabindex=1 onclick="stisk()">OK></input> you may need to add tabindex=2 on the other input field.

Comment: not good accessibility practice. Bind to form submit event and allow keyboard submit using enter key and leave the submit type alone

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
<button onclick="stisk(event)">OK</button>
```

and in javascript

```
function stisk(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

This can be useful in other cases, like default behavior of `<a href` element is to redirect page, so you can prevent default behavior with `event.preventDefault()`

---

even better solution - let your button submit form, but prevent default on form submit

```
<form onsubmit="stisk(e)">
    ...
    <button type="submit">
```

and in javascript

```
function stisk(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

and it will work when submitting form with Enter in input field.